# Getting value of the selected submenu item

Tags: c++, mfc

I have developed a menu, submenu using MFC in C++. The submenu is dynamic and keeps changing.
Upon selection of the dynamic submenu, how do I get its value?
I am really stuck here. I would be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Reserve a range of contiguous resource IDs that you assign to each submenu item. Then use [`ON_COMMAND_RANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab3z9tb.aspx) to respond to the item selection.

Comment: Ok.but with this how can I get the value of the selection made in the submenu?

Comment: I got the selected resource ID, which is assigned to a submenu item.( submenu items are stored actually in an array).so , how do I get the name of the submenu item associated with the resource ID?